# Computing $\int_1^\infty \frac{(\log x)}{x^2(1 + x^\alpha)} \mathrm{d} x$ using the residue method.

Tags: complex-analysis

I wish to compute the integral $\int_1^\infty \frac{(\log x)}{x^2(1 + x^\alpha)} \mathrm{d} x$ for some $\alpha$ using the residue method. Here is my attempt. Would appreciate if anyone could help me out with what is going wrong. Thanks!

Consider the complex integral
$\oint_{C_R} \frac{(\log z)^2}{z^2(1 + z^\alpha)} \mathrm{d}z$ (note that $\log z$ is squared) where $C$ is the contour given by,$[1,R] \cup \{ Re^{i\theta} : \theta \in [0 , \epsilon] \} \cup \{ x e^{i \epsilon} : x \in [R,1] \} \cup \{ e^{i\theta} : \theta \in [0 , \epsilon] \}$ as shown in the figure. Consider the branch corresponding to $\log z \in [-\pi,\pi]$.

[image: 1]

The integrand is holomorphic inside the contour so the complex integral comes out to be $0$ by the residue theorem.

Considering its individual components, the integral over the large circle vanishes as $R \to \infty$. On the other hand, the integral over the small radius $1$ circle is of the order of $-\epsilon^3$. And the integration on the sloped line comes out to be,
$$-\int_{1}^\infty \frac{(\log x + i \epsilon)^2}{1+x^\alpha e^{i \epsilon \alpha}} \frac{e^{-2i \epsilon}}{x^2}\mathrm{d} x$$
Adding together the contour integral over the real line gives,
$$\int_{1}^\infty \frac{(\log x)^2}{1+x^\alpha} \frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{(\log x + i \epsilon)^2}{1+x^\alpha e^{i \epsilon \alpha}} \frac{e^{-2i \epsilon}}{x^2}\mathrm{d} x$$
In the limit $\epsilon \to 0$,
$$ \int_1^\infty \epsilon \frac{\log x}{1 + x^\alpha} - O (\epsilon^3)= 0$$
gives that the original integral itself goes to $0$, which is obviously incorrect. Where am I going wrong?

I think that choosing a different contour, say one that picks $\epsilon = \frac{2 \pi}{\alpha}$ as opposed to $\epsilon \to 0$ might work, but that is a different question and I am interested in finding out the mistake in my understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\log(x)}{x^2(1+x^\alpha)}\,dx=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{z\,dz}{e^z(1+e^{\alpha z})}=\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{z}{e^{(1+\alpha)z}}e^{-n\alpha z}\,dz=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(\alpha(n+1)+1)^2} $$
is related to the Hurwitz $\zeta$ function, so i highly doubt that the LHS can be computed through the residue theorem if $\alpha\not\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: The series expansion of $1/(1+x)$ is only convergent when $| x | < 1$, which is not the case here with $e^{\alpha z}$ for large $z$? Is that a mistake?

Comment: @Television: assuming $\alpha>0$, $$\frac{1}{1+e^{\alpha z}}=e^{-\alpha z}\frac{1}{1+e^{-\alpha z}}$$ and the expansion of $\frac{1}{1+e^{-\alpha z}}$ is allowed.

Comment: Oh, my mistake. Thanks for the clarification! Is your statement saying that the integrand is not holomorphic when $\alpha$ is irrational? Why do you say that the residue theorem cannot be applied?

Comment: Oh, I guess I understand why. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
Besides the OP $\underline{requirement}$, it's possible to evaluate the integral by "$\, real\, $" means. Namely,

\begin{align}
&\bbox[15px,#ffc]{\int_{1}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{x} \over
x^{2}\pars{1 + x^{\alpha}}}\,\dd x} 
\,\,\,\stackrel{x\ \mapsto\ 1/x}{=}\,\,\,
-\int_{0}^{1}{x^{\alpha}\ln\pars{x} \over 1 + x^{\alpha}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\left.-\,\partiald{}{\mu}\int_{0}^{1}{x^{\mu} \over 1 + x^{\alpha}}\,\dd x
\,\right\vert_{\ \mu\ =\ \alpha} =
\left.-\,\partiald{}{\mu}\int_{0}^{1}{x^{\mu} - x^{\mu + \alpha}\over 1 - x^{2\alpha}}\,\dd x
\,\right\vert_{\ \mu\ =\ \alpha}
\\[5mm] \stackrel{x^{\large 2\alpha}\ \mapsto\ x}{=}\,\,\, &
\left.-\,\partiald{}{\mu}\int_{0}^{1}
{x^{\mu/\pars{2\alpha}} - x^{\mu/\pars{2\alpha} + 1/2} \over
1 - x}\,\pars{{1 \over 2\alpha}\,x^{1/\pars{2/\alpha} - 1}}\dd x
\,\right\vert_{\ \mu\ =\ \alpha}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2\alpha}\,\partiald{}{\mu}
\bracks{\int_{0}^{1}\!\!{1 - x^{\mu/\pars{2\alpha} + 1/\pars{2\alpha} - 1} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x -
\int_{0}^{1}\!\!{1 - x^{\mu/\pars{2\alpha} + 1/\pars{2\alpha} - 1/2} \over
1 - x}\,\dd x}_{\ \mu\ =\ \alpha}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2\alpha}\,\partiald{}{\mu}
\bracks{\Psi\pars{{\mu \over 2\alpha} + {1 \over 2\alpha}} -
\Psi\pars{{\mu \over 2\alpha} + {1 \over 2\alpha} + {1 \over 2}}}
_{\ \mu\ =\ \alpha}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbox[15px,#ffc,border:1px solid navy]{{1 \over 4\alpha^{2}}
\bracks{\Psi\, '\pars{{1 \over 2\alpha} + {1 \over 2}} -
\Psi\, '\pars{{1 \over 2\alpha} + 1}}}
\end{align}

$\ds{\Psi}$ is the [Digamma Function](http://people.math.sfu.ca/%7Ecbm/aands/page_258.htm) and I used
${\bf 6.3.22}$ in [this link](http://people.math.sfu.ca/%7Ecbm/aands/page_259.htm).